# How can I find sentences with special word? (Problem: Abbreviations and dots)

Tags: javascript

I wrote code in Javascript which is find sentences with searching dots. But abbreviations are problem. How can I write the code that will ignore abbreviations?

My code:

```js
console.clear();

var text = "They tried to kill Alan Rackham about an hour after he had seen the accident. They bungled the job. They shot at him from ambush—with an ordinary automatic pistol—as he was walking up to his house; and Brave, who had a sixth sense for danger which never failed him, knocked Alan over at the very instant of the shot and sprawled across him, a great solid shield holding him down and protecting him despite his angry wrigglings. Brave's grenade pistol was in his hand before the two of them hit ground, and he sent four quick shots at the bushes, spaced so that the tiny hot fragments tore hell out of thirty yards of shrubbery. Nobody yelled about or groaned. Brave waited a full minute, and then he rose cautiously, so that Alan could sit up and brush himself off and swear as he spat out dirt. They about went into the house and Alan reported the assassination attempt to his immediate superior, Dr. Getty. After that they didn't try again to kill Alan for a long time.";

function searchWord(word) {
  var i = 0;
  var t = 0;
  var c = 0;
  var start = 0;

  while (c == 0) {
    i = 0;
    t = 0;
    var numb = text.indexOf(word, start);
    var numb2 = text.indexOf(word, start) - 1;

    if (text.indexOf(word, start) == -1) {
      document.write("<br>there is no any sentences about your word");
      c = 1;
    } else {

      while (i == 0) {
        if (text.charAt(numb) == ".") {
          i = 1;
          console.log("Ladies and gentlemen, we got him.");
          console.log(numb);

          if (text.charAt(numb + 1) == " " && text.charAt(numb + 2) == text.charAt(numb +
              2).toUpperCase()) {
            console.log("omg, perfect :o");
          } else {
            numb = numb + 1;
          }

        } else {
          numb = numb + 1;
        }
      }

      while (t == 0) {
        if (text.charAt(numb2) == ".") {
          t = 1;
          console.log("Ladies and gentlemen we got him twice");
          console.log(numb2);

        } else {
          numb2 = numb2 - 1;

          if (numb2 == 0) {
            t = 1;
          }
        }
      }

      start = numb;

      if (numb2 == 0) {
        document.write(text.slice(numb2, numb + 1));
      } else {
        document.write(text.slice(numb2 + 1, numb + 1));
      }

    }
  }

}

searchWord("about");
```

Run:
*They tried to kill Alan Rackham about an hour after he had seen the accident. Nobody yelled about or groaned. They about went into the house and Alan reported the assassination attempt to his immediate superior, Dr.*

*there is no any sentences about your word*

Code thinks that "this is end of sentence".

I wanted to create an array that includes mostly used abbreviations, but there is a problem like this: example, if code ignore the abbreviations then program can't define the sentence like this "this is my tel."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a big problem, if you want to do a great job, you need to study Language Processing. It's not only string manipulation, the problem is linked to many parts of the language. I suggest you [nlp.js](https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js), it's the best library to experiment LP in JS.

Comment: Thank you, probably i will learn LP after learning Javascript

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without NLP, or very complex algorithms, or using a very large dictionary with all possible abbreviations.

Your problem is:

```
...this is some sentence with an abbr. to show an example.  The next sentence also using an abbr. will continue...
```

Using the above example there's no way to search for "." and determine that it's a sentence, there's 3 dots in that sentence, both before the sentence ends and also after it started, so you can't even test the length of the string or anything like that.